.show() charts are white until I use renderer='iframe'
I have an issue on my personal laptop, but not on my professional one, so I guess it comes from my laptop config.
when I use plotly express to show a graph, for example:
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import plotly.express as px
stock_df=yf.download("AMZN")
fig = px.line(title = 'Amazon.com, Inc. (AMZN) Adjusted Closing Price [$]')
fig.add_scatter(x = stock_df.index, y = stock_df['Adj Close'], name = 'Adj Close')
fig.show()

it gives my an white empty render, and I am forced to use fig.show(renderer='iframe') if I want to see it.
I had the exact same issue, maybe it comes from the same problem with seaborn, sns.pairplot(daily_returns_df) returns white while sns.pairplot(daily_returns_df, diag_kind=None) works well, and cufflinks where figure.iplot(theme = 'white', up_color = 'green', down_color = 'red').show() returns white and figure.iplot(theme = 'white', up_color = 'green', down_color = 'red', asFigure=True).show(renderer='iframe') works well.
Both techniques work well on my secondary computer.
Do you know where this could come from?

don't spam tags. cufflinks, matplotlib, and seaborn are not relevant to this post.

As per this, the issue is not reproducible with plotly 5.21.0 in python 3.12.0. If you're using jupyter, then make sure you have the plotly extension for jupyter installed and enabled.
